# Table size is 0 in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, internet-explorer-7

I add content of table in Javascript like this

```
function (data) {
        $("#forum-content").html(data);
}
```

data is a string with table content(`"<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>..."`) and I want to add that content to my table.

```
<table id="forum-content"></table>
```

In majority browsers it's look fine, but in IE 7 after adding content I don't see table anyway... I check that problem is that IE 7 is calculating size of my table 0(width=0,height=0) after adding content.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Change the size of the table ?

Comment: Table size is dynamic... All other browsers calculate height and width after adding content.

Comment: What happens if you add the `<table>` with the other content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid writing a table body like that. In IE tables have been traditionally very fragile when using `innerHTML` (which jQuery's `html()` method basically is).

Try building the whole table instead:

```
function (data) {
        $("#forum-content").html("<table>" + data + "</table>");
}
```

with

```
<div id="forum-content"></div>
```

Comment: I finally solve that... Thanks, your answer is really helpful

I saved all in string, then append it like this

var str='<table><tbody>';
    str+=data;
    str+='</tbody></table>';

    $("#forum-content").html(str);

Now it works in IE 7 too)))

Answer (score 0):

In my test, I saw nothing wrong. Do you check whether the content was added to the table? Is there any error thrown.

```
<table id="forum-content">
</table>
<script>
$(function() {
  function addContent(data) {
          $("#forum-content").html(data);
  }
  addContent('<tr><th>Title</th><td>Content</td></tr>');
});
</script>
</body>
```